# gax-java 0.3.0 latest version

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-api

Latest version of gax java (Google Api EXtensions) is 0.3.0 as per [gax-java](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-java), but there is no jar file found for the same .

[Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api) lists version 0.2.0 as the latest. Could some one help me out in finding the latest jar version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven repository has posted the [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api/gax/0.3.0).